# How to set ngModel in ngRepeat value (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

On the code you can see as follows:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm" ng-repeat="sForm in sForms">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{sForm.label}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{sForm.place}}" name="{{sForm.name}}" ng-model="search[sForm.propertyName]" ng-click="searchDisabled(sForm.val)" ng-disabled="{{sForm.disabled}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <input type="radio" class="radio" name="checked" ng-click="searchDisabled(sForm.val)" ng-model="formRadio.checked" value="{{sForm.val}}" ng-hide="{{!sForm.disabled}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

doesn't work the ngModel value `search[sForm.propertyName]`. I don't know why.. Here are the properties:

```
$scope.sForms = [
            {
                label: 'Lastname',
                place: 'Searching lastname',
                name: 'Lname',
                val: 1,
                propertyName: 'lname',
                disabled: $scope.disabledLname,
                hideRadio: !$scope.disabledLname
            },
            {
                label: 'Firstname',
                place: 'Searching firstname',
                name: 'Fname',
                val: 2,
                propertyName: 'fname',
                disabled: $scope.disabledFname,
                hideRadio: !$scope.disabledFname
            }];
```

The disabled value also didn't work. when I check the first input then the second input need to be disabled.

Comment: your code appears to be affected by JavaScript Prototype Inheritance.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs.  `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each iteration, and primitive properties will not operate the way you expect.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for your comment..do you know what I have to do to get the correct values?

Comment: Can you share  a fiddle or a plunker? Also please share the searchDisabled function.